# Animate shape using Jetpack compose for Android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-jetpack-compose

I want to build a great lockscreen using compose like stock Android 12 like this:

[image]

I managed to do something similar, however i have 2 issues, one is when I use `pointerInteropFilter` to get the action events I use a `remember` value to change the shape, returning true in this function I got a similar animation, however the click listener is not called, if I return `false` the shape stays in "square", What I'm missing? is any way to animate the "shape"? I found for DP, color and size but not for shapes.
here is the code

```
@Composable
fun RoundedPinBackground(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    backgroundColor: Color,
    onClicked: () -> Unit,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    var selected by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val shape = if (selected) {
        RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)
    } else {
        CircleShape
    }
    Surface(
        tonalElevation = 10.dp,
        modifier = Modifier
            .clip(shape)
    ) {
        Box(modifier = modifier
            .size(80.dp)
            .clip(shape)
            .background(color = backgroundColor)
            .clickable { onClicked.invoke() }
            .pointerInteropFilter {
                when (it.action) {
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                        selected = true
                    }

                    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                        selected = false
                    }
                }
                true
            },
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            content()
        }
    }
}
```

This are my results

| Syntax | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Motion event true | Motion event false |
| [image: Motion event returns true but no ripple or click] | [image: Motion event returns false but stays in square shape] |

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to animate the radius you need to use one of the `animate*AsState()` APIs.

They key here would be to change the corner radius of your Shape progressively by using `animateDpAsState()`, as a Circle is a `RoundedCornerShape` with the corner radius as half the size of the overall `Circle`.

In order to get the ripple, you can use the clickable modifier with `rememberRipple()` as the indication.

Below is a working example of both:

```
@Composable
fun RoundedPinBackground(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    size: Dp,
    backgroundColor: Color,
    onClicked: () -> Unit,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    val isPressed = interactionSource.collectIsPressedAsState()
    val radius = if (isPressed.value) {
        10.dp
    } else {
        size / 2f
    }
    val cornerRadius = animateDpAsState(targetValue = radius)

    Surface(
        tonalElevation = 10.dp,
        modifier = modifier
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(cornerRadius.value))
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(color = backgroundColor)
                .size(size)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(cornerRadius.value))
                .clickable(
                    interactionSource = interactionSource,
                    indication = rememberRipple()
                ) { onClicked.invoke() },
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            content()
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Animation with radius and ripple]

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot, any idea how to make the "ripple" to work? thanks

Comment: @Javier I've updated the sample to use `rememberRipple()` and extracted `MutableInteractionSource` that exposes the `collectPressedAsState()` instead of using `pointerInteropFilter`